# IntelliJ IDEA: how to restrict project tree view to a couple of folders

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm working with IntelliJ IDEA in a rather large tree of projects almost exclusively on about 5 folders nested deeply in the hierarchy. Ideally I just want to see those 5 folders most of the time - the other projects and the other folders in their projects are usually just visual clutter. How can I get a view as close as possible to this with IDEA?

I do want all projects accessible in my workspace, so I can't just throw away the others. And even that would not help too much, because those folders are deeply nested in their projects. The favorites view almost does what I want, since you can unfold the folders there - but if there are some new files they are often not visible there (not sure whether this is a bug or a feature). Do you have other ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: If you have a folder added to Favorites and new files in this folder don't appear in the project view tree, it's definitely a bug, and we'd appreciate a report in YouTrack.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to do. You can create scopes by criteria.

Go to preferences (mac) -> appearance & behavior -> scopes

There you can create local and shared scopes. You can manually edit these or use a regex pattern. The current reference documentation is located [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scopes.html).

Here are some examples from the jetbrains website of using regex.

`file[MyMod]:src/main/java/com/example/my_package//*` - include in a project all the files from module "MyMod", located in the specified directory and all subdirectories.

`src[MyMod]:com.example.my_package..*` - recursively include all classes in a package in the source directories of the module.

`lib:com.company..*||com.company..*` - recursively include all classes in a package from both project and libraries.

`test:com.company.*` - include all test classes in a package, but not in subpackages.

`[MyMod]:com.company.util.*` - include all classes and test classes in the package of the specified module.

`file:*.js||file:*.coffee` - include all JavaScript and CoffeeScript files.

`file:*js&&!file:*.min.*` - include all JavaScript files except those that were generated through minification, which is indicated by the min extension.

Comment: Good point: If I define a scope (which is even easier using the dialog at scopes) there is a new choice with this scope in the project view that only shows that stuff. Together with "hide empty middle packages" that's more or less what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Np, glad to help.